# How to give active class for database fetch menus in php?

Tags: javascript, php

My problem is I fetch datas from database and display in list, now I want particular menu click it show only that particular menu active. How to do this friends please help me.

**My Code**

```
<ul class="marked-list">
    <li ><a href="agentproducts.php">All</a></li>

         <?php

            mysql_select_db('db_project', mysql_connect('localhost','root','')) or die(mysql_error());

            $query = mysql_query("select menuName from menu") or die(mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

         ?>
    <li class="<?php 

  $menuName="menuName";
  $category="category";
  if ($menuName == $category){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a  href="category.php?menu=<?php echo $row['menuName']; ?>"><?php echo $row['menuName']; ?></a></li><?php } ?>

</ul>
```

But it not active particular menu.

Comment: your condition always become false. because $menuName="menuName"; $category="category"; if ($menuName == $category)

Comment: Please give any  suggession for correct condition friend.

Comment: For this you have to give more details. Update your questions, add detail description. like what is category from when you get category and menu name. I see you are getting result from table "menu". But you are not using it result anywhere.

Comment: check this condtion : if ($menuName == $row['menuName']). Your $menuName must be current link name

Comment: not work Desai thank you for your help.